# predict/optimize a list of integers based on total sum after multiplication with another list

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I have a list like this,

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to predict a list of same size with some ranges

```
 l1=[x(between 1 and 3), x(4,6), x(7,9), x(10,12), x(13,15)]
```

so that the sum of the multiplication of both list is 155.
for example l1 should be,

```
l1=[3, 6, 7, 11, 15],
so, [3, 6, 7, 11, 15] * [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = 3 + 12 + 21 + 44 + 75 = 155
```

Currently I am doing a simulation (using a loop) and generating random numbers of those ranges for each item and repeating the process until the sum is 155.

I am looking for better approach to do it more efficiently.

Comment: Do you need a single compatible list or an exhaustive enumeration thereof?

Answer (score 1):

You can brute force this in a friendlier way than guess-and-check with a simple recursive generator. You basically start with the first range, then recursively check the rest while appropriately altering the total. Example is probably easier to understand:

```
def find_match(l, ranges, total, res=None):
    if res is None:
        res = []
    if not ranges:
        if total == 0:
            yield res
        return
    head, *rest = ranges
    for n in head:
        yield from find_match(l[1:], rest, total - l[0] * n, res + [n])
        
        
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l1 = [range(1, 4), range(4,7), range(7,10), range(10,13), range(13,16)]

for found in find_match(l, l1, 155):
    print(found, sum(a * b for a, b in zip(found, l)))
```

Which prints the solutions and the sum of the product:

```
[1, 4, 9, 11, 15] 155
[1, 5, 7, 12, 15] 155
[1, 6, 8, 12, 14] 155
[1, 6, 9, 10, 15] 155
[2, 4, 9, 12, 14] 155
[2, 5, 8, 11, 15] 155
[2, 6, 9, 11, 14] 155
[3, 4, 7, 12, 15] 155
[3, 5, 8, 12, 14] 155
[3, 5, 9, 10, 15] 155
[3, 6, 7, 11, 15] 155
[3, 6, 9, 12, 13] 155
```